# How do I put my UserID into an array when I log in

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a mySQL database that contains all the user data, I am currently using POST to login but because I am using POST I don't know how I can get the UserID of the user that i used to log in, I am using username and password to log in but I want to get the UserID to put in and array so i can keep the user logged in.

```
function getLoginData() {

    var details = new Object();
    details.UserName = document.getElementById("UserName").value;
    details.UserPassword = document.getElementById("UserPassword").value;

    //alert("uigug");
    var Login = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance to send comment

    Login.open("POST", login_url, true); //Use the HTTP POST method to send data to server

    Login.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Login.onload=function(){
        response = JSON.parse(Login.responseText);
        if (response.message == "1"){
            window.location = "Main1.html"
            alert("Login Successful, Welcome: " + details.UserName)
        }

        else{
            window.location = "Main.html"
            alert("Login Failed")
        }

    }   
        Login.send(JSON.stringify(details)); 

}
```

Comment: A POST request is capable of transmitting user-entered details to the server.. it is the server's job to remember that (if you're using a session mechanism) logged in state after checking them.. you don't seem to send the details object in the post request though?

Answer (score 1):

Your UserID is placed on the database. You have to send the UserID from database using PHP or node etc in response to this request (If you wanna work with that in front end js).